# PriviledgedActionException while running kmeans on hadoop

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce, k-means

I am trying to run KMeans on hadoop, using this guidelines.

http://www.slideshare.net/titusdamaiyanti/hadoop-installation-k-means-clustering-mapreduce?qid=44b5881c-089d-474b-b01d-c35a2f91cc67&v=qf1&b=&from_search=1#likes-panel

I am running this in eclipse-luna. when I executed, both map and reduce are showing they are complete 100%. But i am not getting output. Instead i am getting following error at the end. Please some help me to solve this..

```
15/03/20 11:29:44 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-hduser/mapred/staging/hduser378797276/.staging/job_local378797276_0002

15/03/20 11:29:44 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException as:hduser cause:java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No input paths specified in job


at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:193)


at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:55)


at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:252)


at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:1054)


at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:1071)


at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$700(JobClient.java:179)


at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:983)


at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:936)


at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)


at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)


at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)


at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:936)


at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:550)


at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:580)


at com.clustering.mapreduce.KMeansClusteringJob.main(KMeansClusteringJob.java:114)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the input file location before running the map reduce program. There are two ways for providing the input file location.

1. Using ecliple go to run configration and provide the file name as arguments
2. Convert your program to jar file and run the below command inside your hadoop cluster

   **hadoop jar NameOfYourJarFile InputFileLocation OutPutFileLocation** `

Comment: Actually In the above program, input vectors are hardcoded in main program only. There is nothing external data file.
Any suggestion ?